# Why is the request payload too high (Google Earth Engine)?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export an image of Austria. Here is my code:

```
// Load country boundaries
var countryBoundaries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2017");

// Filter for particular country
var selectedCountry = countryBoundaries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COUNTRY_NA','Austria'))

// Create an image with the elevation data
var elevationImage = ee.Image("USGS/GMTED2010");

// Zoom to the country
Map.centerObject(selectedCountry, 6);

// Define visParams dictionary
var elevationVis = {
  max: 3500,
  min: 130,
  palette: ['0000FF', '006400', '228B22', 'FFD700', 'daa520',
  '800000','8b0000','a9a9a9','FFFFFF']
}

// Clip elevation image to specific country
var countryImage = elevationImage.clip(selectedCountry)

// Display the image on the map.
Map.addLayer(countryImage, elevationVis, 'Elevation');

// Export the image
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: countryImage.visualize({
    max: 3500,
    min: 130,
    palette: ['Blue', 'DarkGreen', 'ForestGreen', 'Gold', 'Goldenrod',
              'Maroon','DarkRed','DarkGray','White']
    }),
  description: 'austria',
  scale: 231.92,
  folder: 'Fall Maps',
  region: selectedCountry,
});
```

For some reason, I keep getting the error `Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.`

I understand why this error occurs. What's weird is that it hasn't happened for every other country I've tried (even large ones like Argentina and Australia). What's going on here?

Comment: You can get around this by using the bounds of the region when exporting: `region: selectedCountry.geometry().bounds()`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by Daniel Wiell, the issue is the use of a complex polygon as the region in the Export call.  This is a quirk of the export calls, where the entire region gets "baked" into the request, and in this case, the region has ~300,000 points in it.

There's no need to use the exact geometry as the region for the export, as the export's bounds will always be rectangular anyway.  You can use the bounds() of the region.